# to cut between = move in the most direct way?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

*How I met my certain fate by Stewart Lee*

> **Cutting between** Gottfried’s grinning face and the sight of people literally falling off their chairs laughing and gasping, in pain, for breath, The Aristocrats made a convincing case for absurdity as a logical response to tragedy.

The author describes how a stand-up comic Gilbert Gottfried made a joke about 9/11. And the audience booed him. Then Gilbert decided to tell the joke called "The Aristocrats joke", and the audience liked it so much, even falling from their chairs with laugh.

Does the author mean that this "Aristocrats" joke made **the most direct** **[cut]** way **between** stand-up comic and the audience?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Cutting between A and B" means changing the image picked up by a camera or displayed on a screen between A and B. In this case, the phrase may refer to someone who was there in person, looking from the comedian's face to the audience. I haven't read enough of the passage to know if a direct view or a screen view was meant, but in any case it refers to the alternation of images.

Comment: Thank you so much!